# Game configuration in C# and XNA

Tags: c#, configuration, xna

What is the simplest way to read and write game  configurations like: whether to show fps or play sound, etc.

Maybe there are some class in xna that can be used to do that?

I don't really want to use default C# XML thingy for an XNA game.

Comment: If you want to read **and write** (at runtime) the easiest way is to use a "default C# XML thingy". Lookup reading/writing XML. It's really not too bad.

Comment: May be this could help you
http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/11306/configuration-management-in-xna

Comment: Yeah, read and write. But what about xbox...? I would like to potentially also be able to port this game to xbox. Will it be possible to read/write xml when running game on xbox?

Comment: @PapaJohn:Note that while that's a good link for loading content/a configuration, the content pipeline doesn't do writing - it's for compiling assets to be loaded into the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've mentioned that you might want to port to the xbox, i'd recommend using a library called [EasyStorage](http://easystorage.codeplex.com/). It's what a lot of people use when doing simple reading/writing.

It deals with allowing the player to choose their storage device (if more than one exist) and with things like the player removing the storage device before trying to save etc. It'll give you a Stream to save/load from, so most of your actual saving/loading code will be the same.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not really what I was looking for, but it is good option if I actually will be deploying for xbox. For now I resorted to xml because there's nothing in the default library specifically made for that task :)

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to propose a much simpler answer. I assume these configuration changes are only for testing during development right? Then why not simply have a static class with your settings:

```
public static class Debugging
{
  public static bool ShowFPS = true;
  public static bool PlaySound = false;
}
```

This way, you don't have to write *any* code for reading the values from disk. All you have to do is something like `if (Debugging.ShowFPS)`. You also don't have to write any code to change the values at runtime other than setting a static field (`Debugging.ShowFPS = false;`).

Think about it, if you store your values in, say, an XML file, your work flow will be:

1. Open file
2. Change value
3. Press F5 to run the game with the changed values

the workflow is exactly the same, with the added benefit that you don't have to write any code to deal with reading and writing. It also works with absolutely no changes on all supported platforms. And if you want to be 100% sure that you don't forget to change a setting before releasing, you can use a simple ifdef with the correct values for production:

```
    public static class Debugging
    {
#if DEBUG
      public static bool ShowFPS = true;
      public static bool PlaySound = true;
#else
      public static bool ShowFPS = false;
      public static bool PlaySound = false;
#endif
    }
```

Sometimes, the best answer is the simplest ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but no... these settings must be saved to disk and read on startup. So the program can remember for example whether to be in fullscreen and so forth.